# The reason why the script written in centos does not work in crontab

Tags: sh

I registered the script to crontab to run every 10 minutes. When I run the script, the log is printed, but if I put it on the cron tab and wait, the log does not appear, so it seems that it does not work. If you have anything I need to add or edit, please let me know :(

my sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
pslist=`ps -ef | grep ffprobe | awk '{print $2}'`
pscount=`ps -ef | grep ffprobe | wc -l`
logs='/apps/kMobile/kEncoderPy/batch/kill_ffprobe.log'
timestamp=`date +%Y%m%d--%H:%M`
echo "[$timestamp] Kill the Batch process Start :: "$timestamp >> $logs
echo "[$timestamp] process ffprobe running count :: "$pscount >> $logs
for pid in $pslist
do
    rtime=`ps -p $pid -o etime | tail -1`
    rtime=$rtime | tr -d ' '
    minutes=${rtime:6:2}

    if [$rtime != "ELAPSED" ]; then
        if [ $minutes -gt 10 ]; then
            `kill -9 $pid` 
            echo "[$timestamp] passed 10 minute kill process id : "$pid >> $logs
            echo "[$timestamp] process kill after ffprobe running count : "$psount >> $logs
        fi
    fi
done
```

my crontab -e

```
*/10 * * * * /apps/kMobile/batch/kill_ffprobe.sh
```

Comment: Redirect the output to a log file on your cron line in order to discover what is going on.

Comment: you probably need a space and quotes here: `if [ "$rtime" != ELAPSED ]; then`, else `[$rtime` is interpreted as a command. Also this line will never work: `rtime=$rtime | tr -d ' '`. Also, `\`kill -9 $pid\`` is useless with the backquotes, remove the backquotes.

Comment: It's a grammatical mistake in the language, so I'm very embarrassed. thank you for telling me!